# how to count the node in elements with linq

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

I have xml that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<planets>
  <planet number="1" diameter="3030 miles" year="88 earth days">
    <name>Mercury</name>
 </planet>
  <planet number="2" diameter="7516 miles" year="225 earth days">
    <name>Venus</name>
 </planet>
  <planet number="3" diameter="7926 miles" year="365 earth days">
   <name>Earth</name>
    <moons>
      <moon diameter="2160 miles">The Moon</moon>
    </moons>
  </planet>
 <planet number="4" diameter="4217 miles" year="687 earth days">
    <name>Mars</name>
     <moons>
      <moon diameter="17 miles">Phobos</moon>
      <moon diameter="9 miles">Deimos</moon>
    </moons>
 </planet>
</planets>
```

I try to make query for count the number of moon.

For example, for Mars I want 2 for result and then I want to compare this with the number who was input in the textbox.

```
var text = Request.Params[0];

             XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/solar.xml"));
             XDocument xresp = new XDocument(new XElement("planets")); 

  if(text != null)
             {

                 IEnumerable<XElement> lune =
                     from b in xdoc.Elements("planets").Elements("planet")
                     where int.Parse(b.Element("moons").Count()) == int.Parse(text) 
                     select b;
                 foreach (XElement xEle in lune)
                     xresp.Element("planets").Add(xEle);
             }


             Response.Clear();
             Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
             Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
             xresp.Save(Response.Output); 
             Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be counting how many `<moon>` elements there are, not the `<moons>` and count that. But you'll want to write the query as so:

```
b.Elements("moons").Elements("moon").Count()
```

When running a query with 0 or more results, you'll want to use `Elements()` to ensure that a collection is returned. If you use `Element()`, either the chosen element is returned or `null` if it does not exist. In your case, not every planet has a `<moons>` element.